# Frequencies calculated over 6 categories

Tags: chi-squared-test, frequency

I have 60 patients with squint classified according to age group into 6 categories and according to prognosis on their treatment into improved and same.

If I want to see if there is a difference among the 6 age groups in regard to prognosis what test statistic should I use?

I tried to use chi square but couldn't apply it, first because I have 6 age groups
and 2 outcomes which are improved or same and this means it is 6 by 2 table while ordinary chi square is 2 by 2 or 2 by 3 table, and second because I got some expected values less than 5.

- What test statistic should use?
- Should it be Fisher's exact test or goodness of fit test or any other test?
- Would correlation work?
- What is the formula for the right test please?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason in principle why chi-square should not be applied to a 6 x 2 table. It is correct that small expected frequencies can be a bit problematic for chi-square. With 60 people and a 6 x 2 table the *average* expected frequency is necessarily 5 but the advice that no expected frequency should be less than 5 has not to my knowledge been promoted in any recent text. A better rule of thumb is that expected frequencies should ideally all be greater than 1.

Fisher's exact test also sounds a distinct possibility, but not correlation.

You need to study a better text, as some of the ideas you have are confused. Alan Agresti has written texts on categorical data analysis at several different levels.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. if I use Fisher's exact test, what will be the equation for it please? I am asking because I am familiar with Fisher's exact test when we have only 2 by 2 table, not 6 by 2. Thanks again

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test and its references. But the practical point is not to have an equation, but to work out how to calculate a P-value with your favourite software.